# Opening IE web driver in selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run a piece of selenium code using IE web driver. I can run the same easily using firefox, without adding much dependencies:

I just used the statement `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` 
and the web driver is opening. But looks like there are additional procedures to open in Internet Explorer browser. I have kept `IEDriverServer.exe` file in my local. And gave these commands:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",C:\\exactlocation\\IEDriverServer.exe");

WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Not sure why the IE browser is not even launching. I have added the dependency in `POM` as well. Please help me as I have to run all my tests in IE.

Comment: Post the StackTrace/Error log

Comment: Hi, the exception or error message helps us to understand better.. if browser is not started due to zones setting, then that exception message clearly says to check/uncheck all zones or something.. if it is due to zoom, browser will open but not navigate to URL, here also error message says change to default 100..

Answer (score 0):

At first try make IE browser zoom equal 100% and then run on IE browser. Open IE browser and press ctrl+O to make zoom to 100% or check under browser settings. To execute scripts on IE, zoom should always be 100%.

Comment: My browser zoom is 100% only by default. Yet facing the above issue.

Comment: You can try setting protected mode settings programatically:-                                         DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
 
 capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
 
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\exactlocation\\IEDriverServer.exe");
 
 
 WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

Comment: Thanks. Am surely going to try this out and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set your zoom level to 100%.
2. Go to Internet Options and under Security , Enable protected mode for all the zone mentioned.
   Try the code again , should work.

   `System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\exactlocation\\IEDriverServer.exe";
   WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();`

For protected mode configuration you can check this [url](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration).

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. Presently I do not have admin rights on my machine and cannot enable protected mode. I will try once it is corrected. You sure it has to do with protected mode?

Comment: could you please post the error once? i have faced similar issues before.

Comment: I havn't implemented error logging in the project yet and getting no error stack as such.