# How Do You Run the IE Driver on Webdriver 2.53.1?

Tags: javascript, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have webdriver 2.53.1 running, and I'm able to use Firefox 45.8esr and Chrome to test. When I try to use IE10, nothing comes up. I'm thinking it's something that's wrong with my driver, but I have the IE 2.53.1 driver.

```
var webdriver = require ('selenium-webdriver'),
    firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

var browser = new webdriver
            .Builder()
            .forBrowser('internet-explorer')
            .usingServer(server_url)
            .build();
```

Am I using the wrong IE driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, change the

`.forBrowser('internet-explorer')` part to `.forBrowser('internet explorer')`

Second, once IE opens up on your server, go to internet options > security > and under each zone, enable protected view.

Some helpful links:

[Opening IE web driver in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31744778/4615579)
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities